# Retain the original name of the image on resize

Tags: images

I need to resize a few existing images in my upload directory so doing some tests with wp_get_image_editor. Please check the example code below.

```
$img = wp_get_image_editor( ABSPATH.'test/flower.jpg' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $img )) {
    $img->resize( 800, NULL, false ); //resize to max-width of 800px.
    $filename = $img->generate_filename( 'custom-suffix-string', NULL, 'jpg');
    $saved = $img->save($filename);

    //information returned by $saved
    echo "Filename: ".$saved['file']."<br>";
    }
```

As you can see I can add a custom suffix with line-4 of the code. So the name of my resized file will be `flower-custom-suffix-string.jpg`. The problem is I need it to return as NULL.

If I use `generate_filename( NULL, NULL, 'jpg');` the echoed result is `Filename: flower-800x667.jpg`. So basically I am trying to get the name of the RESIZED image as `flower.jpg` same as original and get rid of `-800x667` from the name. If the process overwrites/deletes the original file, that would not be a problem. Any suggestions or any other way to achieve this ? TIA.

---

**UPDATE** : I ended up using the code below. Thanks for the tip @Zakir

```
$filename = $img->generate_filename( 'temp', NULL, NULL);
$new_name = str_replace('-temp', '', $filename);
$resized_img = $img->save($new_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `preg_replace()` functions to remove `-800x667` (or any height) from the image.
Like this-

```
$image = generate_filename( NULL, NULL, 'jpg');
echo preg_replace( '/-800x[0-9]{2,4}/', '', $image );
```

Comment: Every image would have dynamic height value, I doubt this would work.

Comment: code updated. Feel free to test and review

Comment: i will test n update, thnx